# Scala Play 2.3 Working with gCloud Storage - any libs to go async?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

At the moment we using http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.19.0 Which only seems to expose a blocking API.

Any suggestions on how to get a non-blocking approach welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, The Google API client is just a simple wrapper around REST calls. If you want async, you will need to code that into your app.